# R - error in for loop

Tags: r

I want to do a for loop with lists.

I tried :

```
for(tri in tripletsFinaux){

   CoefsCrit = apprentissage(data,tri$concurrents,tri$client,tri$depot)

   /* I put actions here but you don't need to see it for my problem */

}
```

In my loop, I launch a function which need the different values of the list tri.
Because tripletsFinaux is a dataframe. And I need the 3 values of each tri to perform my function apprentissage() in the for loop.

tripletsFinaux looks like :

```
head(tripletsFinaux,2)
    depot          client concurrents nbLignes
1 blablabla     blobloblo       tatata      131
2 bliblibli     blublbublu      tututu      231
```

My error is :

```
$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

What can I do ?
I don't know if the error is in the apprentissage() function or in the for loop

Comment: Sounds like you don't have an object named `data`, so R assumes you are trying to use the built-in function `data()`.

Comment: Yeah you are right ... my bad ! Now the problem is different `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` and I don't know if it's in the function or the $ in tri$concurrents ...

Comment: Then it seems like `tri` isn't a list, it's an atomic vector. It's hard to keep guessing, maybe [you could make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061)?

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Are you trying to loop over rows or columns? I can't even tell. What is `apprentissage`? Based on your sample input, what values do you want `tri` to take? Maybe just run `for (tri in tripletsFinaux) {print(head(tri))}` and make sure your loop is doing what you want.

Comment: For example, in the first iteration of the loop. I want `tri$concurrents = tatata`, `tri$client = blobloblo` and `tri$depot = blablabla`. Maybe I am not iterating on the good thing. apprentissage is a function I wrote and it works when I test it out of the loop. So I want tri like : `blablabla ; blobloblo ; tatata ; 131`

Comment: Eventually you can use `mapply()` or `Map()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to loop over the rows, so:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(tripletsFinaux)){

   CoefsCrit = apprentissage(data, tripletsFinaux$concurrents[i], tripletsFinaux$client[i], triplentsFinaux$depot[i])

   # ...

}
```

The above is what you want. The way you have it, `for (tri in tripletsFinaux)` will loop over the columns, one column at a time. I was hoping that would be clear if you ran `for (tri in tripletsFinaux) {print(head(tri))}`.

Comment: That's it ! It works using `for(i in 1:nrow(tripletsFinaux))`, and calling `triplestFinaux[i,colName]`